# is it possible to scroll multiple groups horizontally in Apple Watch App?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

Is it possible to scroll horizontally multiple groups(without using page base navigation) each of which would contain child objects/controls? Similar to that of adding multiple UIViews inside UIScrollview in iOS.
I know its possible vertically as group extends it height to fit its content when its size(**Height**) attribute is set to "*`size to fit content`*", but it doesn't work when we set size(**Width**) attribute to "`size to fit content`".

Answer (score 0):

No.
"`size to fit content`" will only force the groups fit the screen, no more no less. 
WatchOS 2 does not allow content "outside the screen" //larger then the visible view.